# How to have app support .HLP help files in Win7?

Tags: windows-7, vb6, helpfile

How can my app which displays a `.HLP` file be able to display this file in Win7?

Is there a redistributable that could be included with the app to provide this support?

Answer (score 1):

My own program comes with a .chm file for help, and it displays just fine on Win7. I think that Vista and Win7 dropped support for .hlp files, not .chm files.

Comment: Yes, it is `.HLP` files that are the problem. Question edited.  Is the solution to convert `.hlp` file to `.chm`?

Comment: Personally I'd rather do what the answer above suggests. WinHlp32 apparently uses RTF internally, while CHM uses html. So there's no 1-to-1 automatic conversion. Converting here would mean rewriting the whole thing from scratch. It could be a significant effort.

Answer (score 1):

Just install [Windows Help program (WinHlp32.exe) for Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=91)

Comment: Note that it is NOT redistributable and you can not include it with your application.

Comment: As a workaround, his installer could download WinHlp32 from MSDN and then execute it. That way he's not redistributing it.

Comment: No, that isn't permitted either.

Comment: You could search for the existence of the WinHlp32.exe and if not found throw up a message and then open up the web page to allow the user to download it?

Answer (score 0):

Am using Win 8, x64, and l tried my best running .hlp files, even downloaded Winhlp32.exe from Microsoft but to no avail. However, l copied winhlp32.exe from WinXp OS and put it on my Win8 and everything worked fine and now, l can view .hlp files on Win8. I think it worth trying.